# Relations in sql DataBase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new and have a database and two tables:

```
UsersTable contains userID(smallInt),Name,Family
ActivitiesTable contains WorkTime,RestTime,Date,userID(smallInt)
```

I want to get this in one DataGrid (when i add new record):

```
userID:A WorkTime: 08:00 RestTime:14:00 Date:12.10.2012
userID:A WorkTime: 08:30 RestTime:14:00 Date:12.11.2012
userID:B WorkTime: 08:00 RestTime:15:00 Date:12.12.2012
.
.
.
```

How can make relations for both tables (using Primary Key and Foreign Key)?
many thanks

Comment: Relations aren't what you think they are. They're actually (roughly) synonymous with tables. What you're referring to is probably a *relationship*, though I'm not sure, because I don't quite understand the question. What does "make relations" mean, exactly? Are you wanting to join the two tables in a query or define a foreign-key relationship between them?

Comment: ok, i want foreign-key relationship.

Comment: Then why did you accept an answer that solves the query interpretation? @faester's answer explains how to define a foreign-key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put userID as primary key in UsersTable and as foreign key in ActivitiesTable (eventually you can put it as primary key as well if the connection is one-to-one).
Then fill your DataGridView with this snippet (it shows how to display a complete list of data). If you want to to keep using DataBinding I suggest not adding brand new items one by one, but just refreshing the underlying DataTable and refreshing DataGridView.

Basically the optimization might be adding new rows to DataTable and refreshing without getting all the data from the database (since already have it, because you've just inserted it into the DB).

Sorry for my bad English. I hope I was clear enough.

```
    try
    {
        var bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

        // Automatically generate the DataGridView columns.
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        // Set up the data source.
        bindingSource1.DataSource = GetData("Select * From UsersTable Inner Join ActivitiesTable"));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

        // Automatically resize the visible rows.
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = 
DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        // TODO manage errors
    }
}

private static DataTable GetData(string sqlCommand)
{
    var connectionString = "%your connection string%";
    var northwindConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, northwindConnection);
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    adapter.SelectCommand = command;

    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    adapter.Fill(table);

    return table;
}
```

P.S. If you DB server/engine providers Linq extension you can use it instead of hardcoded queries (SqlCommand + string) (just take the code from the answer below).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  name, workTime, restTime, [date]
FROM    usersTable u
JOIN    activitiesTable a
ON      a.userId = u.userId
```

Comment: its inner join ...i think not only join..

Comment: @PranayRana: JOIN implies INNER JOIN. Inner joins are so much more common than outer joins that most people don't bother wasting keystrokes to make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You could create using

```
CREATE TABLE UsersTable (userID smallInt NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
       Name NVARCHAR(255),
       Family NVARCHAR(255))

CREATE TABLE ActivitiesTable (WorkTime DATETIME,
     RestTime DATETIME,Date DATETIME, 
     userID smallInt NOT NULL REFERENCES UsersTable (userid), 
     id int not null identity (1,1))
```

I have added an id column to `ActivitiesTable`. You should also consider using `INT` rather than `smallint`, since the performance and space gain is neglectible in most cases.

And as the other responses correctly points out the select is simple

```
Select v.userID, WorkTime, RestTime, Date   
from userTable user inner join ActivitiesTable activity
on user.userid = activity.userid
```